# Reachability app iPhone OS4 SDK issues

Tags: reachability, ios4

Apple's reachability application crashes at runtime after successful compile.  Given the extent to which these routines are implemented, has anyone discovered the correction for this?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

I get rid of the crash by commenting the line 175 of the Reachability.m file:

```
173 + (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;
174 {
175     //[super init];
176     struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
177     bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
```

Comment: I'm upflagging this because I just encountered the bug while working on my 4.0 port.  That is a REALLY annoying error on Apple's part.  It'll also teach me not to do line-by-line reviews of code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 01/06/2010, there is a minor bug fixes.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html